# Provide feedback after a user clicks submit

Tags: javascript, html

After a user clicks Submit, how can I get a pop-up box or something simple that says, "Thanks"? The simplest way possible:

```
<div id="suggestion">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-info" />
```

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
    // Email of sender
    $videogamename = $_POST['namevideogame']; 

    // From (Sender Name)
    $artistname = $_POST['nameofartist'];

    $header = "from: Game AMV";

    // Message
    $message = "Name of Video Game: ".$videogamename."\r\n\nName of Artist/Song: ".$artistname."\r\n\nLink: ".$_POST['link'];

    // Enter your email address
    $to ='something@gmail.com';

    $send_contact = mail($to, 'New Song Suggestion from gameamv.com', $message, $header);

    // Check, if message sent to your email 
    // display message "We've recived your information"
    if($send_contact){
        header("location: http://gameamv.com/");
    } else {
        echo "Error. The form was not submitted. Please try again.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just give alert('Thanks.....'); is this what you are looking for?

Comment: "After a user click Submit, how can I get a pop-up box or something simple that says, "Thanks"? The simplest way possible" - or don't, which is a preferable UI design...

Comment: Remember to issue `exit;` after you execute `header('Location: $url');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - give your `<form>` element a recognizable `id` value.

Then you would hook into the `onsubmit` event as follows:

```js
document.getElementById('myThankfulForm').addEventListener('submit', function () {
    alert("Thankful Form is Thanking you!");
}, false);
```

Here's a demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RV47J/1/).

Comment: After I click the submit button, the pop up comes up, then if I click okay or close, this comes up, 

document.getElementById('myThankfulForm').addEventListener('submit', function () { alert("Thankful Form is Thanking you!"); }, false);

How do I not show that?

Comment: @VinhTran Do you mean that on your page that comes up, or in jsFiddle?

Comment: I got it working, weird. This is why I hate coding. I did the exact same thing the first time and did not work. Delete and did it again and everything worked. Thanks for your help! Awesome stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to pop out after sending the email (after page reload), I would put a message in a Session value before you redirect to the landing page. Then on the landing page, check if that Session value is set, if it is have the landing page echo some Javascript to alert the message then set the Session value to null.

Of course I'm assuming this is one application.